# Meteor app running on Digital Ocean droplet stopped working, mongodb seems to have stopped

Tags: mongodb, meteor, digital-ocean

I have a Meteor app running on a Digitial Ocean droplet via MUP. It's suddenly stopped working - the website is not available. I did not do an update or touch the server in any way, it's just gone away!

It looks maybe like Mongodb has stopped running, but I don't know how to check this, how to start it again or how to find out why it stopped.

I'm running METEOR@1.2.1

UPDATE: simply restarting mongod seems to have got it running again:

```
service mongodb restart
```

So now I'm mostly wanting to find out what happened. Could it be that the server on the droplet restarted and didn't automatically restart mongod?

I've used SSH to connect to the server and tried the command line 'mongo' with the following result:

```
root@myappname:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: test
2016-07-25T06:58:23.244-0400 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-07-25T06:58:23.244-0400 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

I tried mup logs -f with the following result:

```
[my.ip.address] error: Script restart attempt #74021[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address] /opt/myappname/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address] [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address] throw(ex);[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address] [my.ip.address]     [my.ip.address]  [my.ip.address]  [my.ip.address]  [my.ip.address]  [my.ip.address]  [my.ip.address]  [my.ip.address] ^[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address] Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017][my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at Object.Future.wait (/opt/myappname/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:213:1)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:1)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:1)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:102:1)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (accounts_common.js:23:18)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at new AccountsServer (accounts_server.js:16:5)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at Package (globals_server.js:5:12)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at /opt/myappname/app/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1814:4[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     - - - - -[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/opt/myappname/app/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/opt/myappname/app/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/myappname/app/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at net.js:441:14[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address]     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)[my.ip.address] 
[my.ip.address] error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8[my.ip.address]
```

I tried mup deploy which failed with these messsages:

```
mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

“ Checkout Kadira!
  It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
  Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”

Building Started: .

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'myappname' (linux)
[my.ip.address] - Uploading bundle
[my.ip.address] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[my.ip.address] - Setting up Environment Variables
[my.ip.address] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[my.ip.address] - Invoking deployment process
[my.ip.address] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    -gyp/0.10.40',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/myappname/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    gyp info ok 
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data

    /usr/lib/node_modules/wait-for-mongo/bin/wait-for-mongo:14
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: TIMEOUTED_WAIT_FOR_MONGO
        at null._onTimeout (/usr/lib/node_modules/wait-for-mongo/lib/waitForMongo.js:20:14)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    .1:27017]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [my.ip.address]
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm new to server management and would be very grateful for any help or suggestions.

Many thanks

Comment: maybe, mongo just crashed. it is usually very resilient even with invalid json. something terrible might have crashed it. difficult to trouble-shoot production systems. if it can be reproduced in dev, it is possible to do something about it.

Comment: Update: I found some instructions for increasing the memory allocation on the server, and the problem hasn't recurred.